# wireless iphone app distribution - install does not work

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a problem similar to [wireless iphone app distribution - problem with itms-services protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695180/wireless-iphone-app-distribution-problem-with-itms-services-protocol). When I click on the link pointing to the plist file in safari on the device, the link briefly flashes but nothing happens. I've checked the following:

- the ipa installs ok using itunes
- the mime types are set (i've checked the http headers returned from the server)
- there are no spaces or special chars in the url's and the url's are fully qualified

What I did notice is that I can't access ocsp.apple.com from my ipad, my mac or anywhere really, browser, telnet, etc. Is it only open on a specific port? I tried to proxy network traffic from my ipad to my mac to see the network traffic but all I see is the 200 response returning the plist file. If I tether the ipad and watch the console logs, I sometimes see:

> Jan 31 14:39:56 unknown wifid[27] : WiFi:[349731596.044674]: Client itunesstored is background application

Comment: If you're trying to distribute wirelessly have you tried Test Flight?