# Apple OTA App Distribution: App Download Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, ota

i've an issue regarding to manage downloading an App via OTA.

This [link](http://www.paradeofrain.com/2010/11/taking-the-pain-out-of-ad-hoc-testing/) shows pretty well, how to begin and it's the same i did in the following step:

After I created an App in Xcode 4.3.1 for Archiving (Product -> Archive) with a Developer Provisioning Profile, i was able to see the App in the Organizer. 
After selecting the and and clicking the "Distribute..." - Button, i selected the option "Safe for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment". Next step, i selected the Code Signing Identity, i compiled the app with (the Developer Provisioning Profile). Than i selected the checkbox "Save for Enterprise Distribution" and filled out the Application URL (http://www.mycompany.com/test/MyApp.ipa) and the Title ("My App") (which was required). After Saving the ipa file to a specific folder, i uploaded the mobileprovisionprofile, the ipa ("MyApp.ipa") and the plist ("MyApp.plist") on the server at the given Resource URL (http://www.mycompany.com/test).

Then i had to create a page (index.html) in which a link to the app manifest (MyApp.plist) was being added:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.mycompany.com/test/MyApp.plist">
```

Btw, also a link to the Provisioning Profile was being added, so its easy to install the profile also.

I can install the Provisioning Profile using the mobile safari pretty well, but when i click on the Manifest Link an error dialog pops up and says like "Can not connect to www.mycompany.com".

Is there an issue with the ipa oder the plist file?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer in another [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695180/wireless-iphone-app-distribution-problem-with-itms-services-protocol).

One of the answers was, that there might be a problem with the server and it was the right answer for me.

All we did was to ensure that the MIME types where set correctly and that the file was accessible.

Thank you Shoerob