# canOpenURL always return FALSE

Tags: ios, uiapplication

I´m trying to open an URL with UIApplication, but when I run:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlToUpdate
```

The url is created with a String and

```
NSString *urlStringToOpenEscaped = [urlStringToOpen stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *urlToUpdate = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringToOpenEscaped];
```

Always returns FALSE.

I checked the URL is accessible from the iPad.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you show the url string (urlStringToOpenEscaped ) for us?

Comment: sure: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://address/App.plist`

Comment: Have a look at the comments in the first answer here. It might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695180/wireless-iphone-app-distribution-problem-with-itms-services-protocol

Comment: Thankssss, I will try to review all cases.
Additional information:  I´ve checked that the URL: `http://address/App.plist` returns TRUE in the call, `canOpenURL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canOpenURL` method is not meant to be used in order to test if a network url is reachable. According to the documentation:

> This method guarantees that that if openURL: is called, another
>   application will be
>       launched to handle it. It does not guarantee that the full URL is valid.

So, it's a way of knowing if the resource specified by the url passed to the method, can be accessed/opened by an application on the system.

If you want to check whether a web address is reachable or not you'll have to execute the request and then handle the result in the response.

Comment: I knew it, so previous to the call to UIApplication I checked with NSURLConnection that the resourse is avaliable, and I received a status 200.

If I delete the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlToUpdate]` when I do the call to [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlToUpdateWithHeaders]; doesn´t work, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

IOS 9 has some policy changes in using canopenURL to prevent ad services from misusing the API.

http://www.macrumors.com/2015/06/24/ios-9-policy-change-advertising-privacy/

Comment: That's not it, it's not the info.plist for comgooglemaps. There's something else wrong. Probably a bug in GoogleMaps or iOS, or both